# Running 220v and 110v power supply on same computer

Tags: power-supply

I'm trying to run a 13 card Ethereum mining server and I have dual 1,600W PSUs on 220V but it's not powerful enough for the 13 R9 290s that run @ 300W a piece, totaling 3,600W in power. I have a spare 700W PSU that runs on 110V, so I was wondering if I could connect the cards to that PSU to get it all running.

Comment: Power supply to card sets, not Power supply to Power supply.

Comment: I’ve never seen a computer power supply that was 110V-only. Usually they have a switch on the back for 120/240. Some new ones work on either automatically.

Comment: I heard that the cost of power was more than the currency mined at this point. What is your info? Mine is an ROI in 26 yrs. (no pun intended)  You'll want to have the voltages balanced for bus sharing.

Comment: for real power try 13 units of Antminer S9

Comment: @τεκ Some PSUs omit the 110/230V switch so users cannot blow them up. Running an 110V PSU on a 220V circuit will result in smoke.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Computer power supplies are isolated.

Comment: Nitpick: PE is *not* isolated, of course, but should be the same unless you have some serious electrical problems.